# Gettting undefined method `empty?' for nil:NilClass in my test suite when I try to call a Rails path helper (*_path) using Rails, Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rspec-rails

Rails 6.1.3.1
Rspec

Basic behavior spec code:

```
describe "index" do
  it "should show me the list" do
    visit dashboard_targets_path
  end
end
```

The routes file

```
namespace :dashboard do
  resources :targets 
end
```

The error shows me the exception, but strangely it appears as if it isn't calling through to the app, just fails right in my test code:

```
  1) interaction for Dashboard::TargetsController index should show me the list
     Failure/Error: visit dashboard_targets_path
     
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `empty?' for nil:NilClass
     # ./spec/system/dashboard/targets_behavior_spec.rb:16:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # /Users/jason/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/webmock-3.12.2/lib/webmock/rspec.rb:37:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
     # /Users/jason/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/rspec-wait-0.0.9/lib/rspec/wait.rb:46:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
```

It seems to be failing *inside* the test code, if I drop into the debugger there and run `dashboard_targets_path` directly  I also get the same exception, so the problem is just using the helper **within the TEST ENVIRONMENT**

Within the dev environment, this function works.

Answer (score 3):

The problem here was the the `config/environments/test.rb` file does have `default_url_options`.

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'localhost', port: 3000 }
```

When you hit errors that disappear into the Rails gems, a good way to debug them is like so:

```
begin
  // your failing code here
rescue StandardError => e
  puts e.backtrace
  byebug
  puts e.inspect
  raise (e)
end
```

*WARNING: do not leave this code in your app or check it in unless you explicitly want to use exception handling for flow control (not recommended!). This is recommended ONLY for debugging purposes.*

Here you will see the full backtrace to the line number in the *Gem* where it is failing. When debugging Gems be careful— remember to undo any changes you make and know that your monkey-patching inside of the Gem code doesn't affect your production code.

Note that you can run `gem pristine <gem name>` or `gem pristine --all` to undo any changes made to locally installed gems.